# Jqplot with single series, varybarcolor and legend

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm creating a bar chart.

I have a single series:

```
var s1 = [2, 4, 0, 1]
```

I want to vary the bar color so i use:

```
rendererOptions: {varyBarColor : true}
```

I also want to display a legend that matches the color of each bar but as there is only one series, the legend only shows one series.

Is it possible to have the legend display the colors of each of the bars?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$.jqplot` rather than passing in just the single series `s1`:

```
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {...
```

instead pass in `[s1,[],[]]`

```
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1,[],[]], {...
```

Also ensure the `labels` property of `legend` is set to ticks so the labels in the legend correspond to the x-axis ticks (Equities, Bonds, Property etc):

```
legend: { 
    show: true, 
    placement: 'outside',
    labels: ticks
}
```

This will render as follows:

[image]

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dH7Hm/116/) for an example.